# How to receive/process an uploaded file in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, mod-plsql, oracle12.1

I'm tasked with modding a legacy web app to allow internal users to submit a csv file to be processed into several different tables in our Oracle 12.1 database.  This web app's HTML content is almost entirely generated in PL/SQL (`htp.p()` calls).  So, I'd like to be able to receive and process the csv file in PL/SQL, if not too complicated.  I know that uploaded files automatically get saved to whatever table is defined in the dads.conf `PlsqlDocumentTablename` parameter.  And it saves it as a BLOB, which, for my purpose, seems to complicate things since it's all text.

Is there a way to bypass or turn off that automatic file-saving-as-BLOB and just pass the file contents to a PL/SQL procedure as something else (CLOB)?  Or a simple way to access the text from the BLOB field and parse it on a line-by-line basis as it would be if it were being read from a text file? (Yes, I've searched SO for handling text from a BLOB and it wasn't encouraging.)

If needed, I can just implement this particular functionality in a Perl script, but I'd like to keep it in PL/SQL if possible (and not too much of a PITA).

Comment: This is a question for the front-end technology you are using, not an Oracle question. You should resubmit the question with the appropriate tag for that tech. However, if you end up not succeeding at changing how it "uploads" these files and you have to work with a BLOB, you can do that. You'll use PL/SQL to convert the BLOB to a CLOB (dbms_lob.converttoclob), then you'll have to loop through it extracting line by line and field by field and process into the final tables as needed. It can be done, but PL/SQL isn't great a text processing like this. Front-end tech might handle it better.

Comment: @PaulW, the front-end is merely a standard HTML form with an enc-type of multipart/form-data and an input of type "file".  Pretty standard.  It sends the form fields to a PL/SQL procedure via mod_plsql.  mod_plsql automatically handles file submittals by storing the file contents in a BLOB field in the table configured for such in the dads.conf.  I'm asking if there's a way around that process while still using PL/SQL.  Hence, an Oracle/ PL/SQL / OHS question  I may end up having the form submitted to a Perl script to handle the file submittal instead but I'd like to keep it "pure" PL/SQL.

Comment: Got it.. so hopefully someone who knows this mod_plsql middleware product can help with how to customize it (this is the first I've ever heard of it). But you have to have some technology to connect to the database, and that's where you need advice. You might want to consider a more well-known tech. Perl, PHP, Python, lots of options out there. That won't be PL/SQL. PL/SQL is for internal DB work. Once your data gets into the database, you can of course use PL/SQL to perform further post-processing, but ideally your data will already be relationally stored so there wouldn't be a need.

Comment: @PaulW I believe mod_plsql is the pre-Apex http interface from around the 9i era. (I've never used it either.)